# LG G3 device not recognized by Eclipse on Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, lg

I recently bought LG G3 and I have enabled debugging mode but Eclipse is still not recognizing it, back when I used the Galaxy S3 for development I had to install Samsung Kies. The G3 drivers are installed and I can see it in My Computer, do I need something like the Kies but for the LG? If so can someone please post a link for that?

Comment: Install google drivers from your device manager.

Comment: I have a similar issue, too, so I'll add some details: the device comes up showing MTP, but no other device is listed in the device manager... that is, no device that would normally be used to attach the ADB drivers to. Toggling debugging mode doesn't work, either. @Tal: What version of the G3 do you have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this solution :

1. Right click on My Computer --> Properties --> Device Manager
2. Right Click on your device --> Update driver software
3. Click on "Browse my computer for driver software"
4. Give path of your android sdk like "D:\Android_Sdk\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" and tick "Include subfolders"
5. Click
6. Now repeat the steps till "*Browse my computer for driver software*".
7. Then click on "Let me pick form list of device drivers on my computer". Click on the first option and click next and then click yes. Drivers will be installed for your device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, the fist step the Driver was allready updated. right after the second step done the device itself asked me to install it drivers again and this time it worked... So i guess i should say THANK YOU!

Comment: there is no 'usb_driver' folder: D:\android_workstation\sdk\extras\google\  just 'google_play_services' and 'm2repository' folders. please help.

Comment: @Usman : Open up your sdk manager, then go to Extras section, check on Google USB Driver option and install it.

Answer (score 36):

**See update below**

---

I found the answer that worked for me.

When you plug in the phone, bring down the status shade, pick the USB item ("USB connected") then, from there, pick "Internet connection" -- I chose Ethernet, but I'm not sure the choice matters on the dialog that pops up..

This enables USB debugging to become active; leaving it on Charging, MTP, or PTP *does not work*.

Once you do this, you can follow @Siddharth's steps to setting the ADB drivers, if needed. (You may need to use the actual LG drivers and not the Google drivers, but once I got this far, it was just like any other phone.)

**Caveat**

For me, even after going through this once, I still get the "installer" first and then have got go in and choose the "Internet connection" again. But, at least it works.

---

**Update 10 Dec 2014**

A recent firmware update has, indeed, removed the "Internet connection" as an option. Instead, PTP now works. I still get the "Connected as an installer" notification every time I plug in the phone and have to click on the notification then click on "Camera (PTP)" -- or wait about a minute. It's slightly better than what It was.

**Also note**: When this change occurred I had to install the drivers again for the phone, since it comes up as a different type of device when "Camera (PTP)" is chosen than when I used the "Internet connection" option.

Comment: So weird.  This was the only thing that worked for me.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to choose the Internet Connection option before I was able to do any debugging.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This also worked for me (the accepted answer did not). Very strange and unintuitive, but at least it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, after trying multiple different solutions, this one worked.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. I can't find the Internet connection. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: My understanding is that "Internet Connection" was removed from the USB options menu in a recent update.  I'm trying to find an up-to-date solution for this, no luck so far.  Setting it to "Camera (PTP)" works but means dealing with multiple popups and having to change settings every time you plug in USB.

Comment: This worked for me on Mac while trying to use the Build and Run option with Unity.

Comment: Trying to use adb from command line on Mac. This was the only solution I could find.

Comment: thank you, MIDI device option worked for me and as soon as I chose that, it immediately asked me to accept the RSA key and it worked right away after that.

Answer (score 22):

For me, this has solved the problem: simply go to LG's website, http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-manuals, select the model (I have selected 'D850') and go to Software Updates tab where you can download the driver. I have installed it and then Eclipse recognized my device. I'm working on Windows 8.1, by the way.

yakobom

Comment: the only solution that worked for me too. Windows 7 here

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! I have LG-D855 and D855 is not listed. I tried D850 or D852 and it worked for me.

Comment: Great. Actually, I had to do this in several computers since the first time, and this solution is the only one that have worked for me.

Comment: Windows 7 / Android Studios user here.  Your solution worked for me, when all others failed.

Comment: This fixed it for me - although to get the drivers for the D855 I had to go to the UK site (the US one doesn't display drivers for this model)

Comment: on Windows 7, I went to http://www.lg.com/uk/support/software-manuals and downloaded the usb driver for windows. The following link is for LGD855 http://tool.xcdn.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425   it's a 12.5MB file. I hope there's not going to be a bunch of junk in it. NOTE: after you plug in your LG G3, wait a couple of mins whilst windows does something with the drivers. Then the phone shows in DDMS

Comment: thanks my friend , wasting time on crazy solutions , just simple :)

Answer (score 14):

After a lot of searching and trying all solutions still I couldn't connect my LG G3 to eclipse on mac. Finally I find this solution, it works for me hope for you works too:

1. Install LG USB driver for mac
2. Go and enable developer mode in your G3 (Setting->About phone (in General Tab)--> Software information --> Tap 8  times on Build Number) then you will see the message which says the Developer option is enabled
3. In this step you expect that after connecting your mobile via USB cable, the Eclipse detect it 
   But for me it didn't happen
4. in this step you need to go (Setting--> Developer Options--> and turn off this option from above green (on/off) switch then again switch on this option from same place (If you don't do this step the "USB Debugging" mode will stay fray and you can not enable it)
5. In Developer Options menu scroll down until find the "USB Debugging" then tic it and enable it.
6. almost finished , you should back and configure running mode for your application and see the G3 in your connected usb devices

Comment: Step number four is what it did it for me. Who would've guessed. Thank you!

Comment: on the mac, all I had to do was switch the USB connection to PTP

Comment: i was missing step 5, ticking  "USB Debugging" . i thought Top On/Off is enough. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Change the USB mode to PTP and you will get the RSA prompt.

Within the prompt, select `allow it` > `ok` and you are done.

This worked for me when I had the same problem on a Mac computer.

Comment: The person asking the question references 'My Computer' -- something meaning they are using a Windows machine, not a machine running OSX.

Comment: this worked for me on windows 7, enable PTP to get RSA prompt. cool

Answer (score 12):

To contribute to possible solutions for this fix: I am using an LG G3 on a Mac.

In my case, ADB saw it as a device when I checked, and the Mac showed the device information in the System Information window, yet Eclipse did not see it. I also did not get the RSA confirmation pop-up when I connected the device through USB.

To fix, with my G3 connected, I selected the USB PC Connection (either from the navigation bar or through the settings) and changed it to be Send Images (PTP). Once this was on, I was given the RSA pop up and Eclipse recognized the phone in the Run Configurations window.

Comment: Using PTP worked for me as well. Not sure why none of the other solutions worked, this is a strange bug.

Answer (score 7):

If you have this problem on Ubuntu; here is what I did to get it working:

1. Switch to PTP from MTP on the phone (this assumes you're connected via USB)
2. Disconnect the USB cable
3. Go to settings -> developer options and select revoke usb authorizations then ok
4. Make sure USB Debugging is checked
5. Reconnect the USB cable and your phone will say its connected as an installer; wait a minute or three and debugging mode should appear on the status bar (on the phone)
6. Open Eclipse and go to DDMS
7. Select "reset adb" in the dropdown if your phone isn't appearing yet

Comment: Thank you! your instructions worked for LG Leon too.  I was missing Google USB (usb_driver) in sdk/extras/google folder  http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 2):

Working on Windows 7. All of the solutions from other sites didn't help (i.e. restarting adb and switching between MTP, PTP, Charing).  In the end, I found this article (http://www.technobuzz.net/install-lg-g3-lg-drivers-windows-mac-usb-adb/), which contains links for the necessary drivers for the lg g3 (and some others I think).  This did the trick and made the RSA key fingerprint dialog appear finally.  After confirming, adb and eclipse recognize my device perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I had this buggy error with my LG Optimus L3 phone connecting to Win7/8 machines!

**Cause:** Device Driver was missing as it seemed at the end when I fixed it!

**How to Fix:**

1. Search through web (using Google) "**LG < Your_Phone_Model Number > Drivers Download**".(Ex.:- Go to About phone in your settings list **>** Model Number, for me it's LG-E400f)
2. Mostly the first few links are related to the required Device Driver download page.(Ex.:- for me I got the following [link](http://www.lg.com/au/support-mobile/lg-Optimus-L3-E400F) and for each device driver LG or most of the other vendors/manufactures have that kind of a Manuals and Drivers Page) Visit that page mentiioning about software update and drivers downloads.
3. Scroll down to the section of "Manuals and Software Update" and doing just the **Step 1** was enough for me, which is "Install the **USB DRIVERS** "
4. Download it(for Mac or Windows) **>** Install It **>** Check Your Eclipse ADT **>** and it should be visible under Devices tab by now

Cheers!!!
Hope this helps to someone else to clearly get to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

it seems that Eclipse shows the offline mode for **lg G3 and some newer devices**
and there is no way no use these devices for ADB debugging

**there is a way**

**I am using windows 10**

1- download this 11 MB file < http://dl2.uncox.com/android/upload/platform-tools-v22.zip>

2- then go to the directory that you installed the SDK

3- extract the zip file in to the platform-tools folder , override all files(click yes to all) be sure that Eclipse doesn't running

4- open Eclipse and select your android device that stands in devices tab at the right-top corner of your screen and then you can see the arrow near the screen- capture icon and you will find the reset-ADB. click on it ,after that your phone will ask you to allow android debugging for your device click on it

5- congratulations .now you can see that your device shown online

i hope this will help .sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I also had a great deal of trouble when attempting to debug android applications on my shiny new LG G3.  What ended up working for me was first installing the default google drivers onto the G3 and then following the process detailed by @lilbyrdie.

The process of installing the google usb drivers is very nicely gone through [here](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/).

However, with the most recently pushed android update to the G3 there are no longer the options for internet connection or charge only; but they seem to have fixed this defect forcing you to make this odd choice to enable debugging.  The only options remaining are MTP and PTP, but if you pull down the notification drawer, choose the 'USB connected' notification (assuming the device is connected to your computer via USB of course) and from there click on 'Media sync (MTP)' **even if it is already selected** then debugging should be enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the two popup dialogs this opens on the host PC?  (On my setup, this opens up a Finder window when I plug in to USB, and an "Image Capture" window when I switch the mode.)

Comment: For anyone hitting the same problem, I managed to at least solve the Image Capture popup with this: http://debugfix.com/2011/11/os-x-image-capture-opens-plug-iphone/

Comment: And to get it to connect straight into MTP mode instead of the useless "installer" mode, these instructions: "Open the stock dialer app, then enter the code "##3328873" and press send. It'll prompt for a service code, which is (of course) "000000". While the Verizon G3 appears to be missing a large chunk of the hidden menus, this section still seems to work. One of the options is a checkbox for "Tool Launcher enable" - uncheck it to disable the Verizon autorun installer." -- Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=55725408&postcount=1

Answer (score 0):

Android can't update on the fly the developer mode. So, after turning on developer mode (and given you have the latest driver) switch the green button(under settings->general->developer options) to off and then back on. Then turn debug mode on (after that windows recognizes a new device) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution for Windows 7 was helpful to update Android SDK Tools to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

**ADB Single/Composite values for LG G3 phones -**

I found it was necessary to update (~userName/.android/)adb_usb.ini file with the line 0x1004:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

0x2207
0x1004
```

In addition, I needed to add the following entry in (.../sdk/extras/google/usb_driver/)android_winusb.inf:

```
;
; Android WinUsb driver installation.
;
...
[Google.NTx86]
...

;LGE Android Phone
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_633E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_631D&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_631D&MI_01

[Google.NTamd64]
...
```

Oh, and set USB to PTP as well as turn-on USB debugging. 
When you're all done with the file modifications and several passes at installing the drivers (ref. earlier posts), you can verify your phone is ready via the Device Manager.  It will list your phone as "Android Device"->"Android Composite ADB Interface".  I believe an earlier post explains setting up the drivers