# Can't install Android drivers

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to mobile development, and I'm trying to get a working development space set up to build and test apps.

I'm trying to use my LG G3 to test apps. I can't get the virtual machine to work, but from my experiences with following directions exactly as they say and triple-checking to make sure I didn't do anything wrong, I didn't really expect it to anyway, and I don't really care as long as I can get debugging to work on an actual device.

Except that I can't get the driver to install. When I plug in the device, it detects it as "VS985 4G", a device with two drives: "Internal storage" and "SD card". I tried updating the driver for "VS985 4G"; I go to device manager, right-click the device (under "Portable Devices"), and select "Update Driver Software..."; I click "Browse my computer...", and type in "extras\google\usb_driver" (replacing  with the path to my sdk); then I click next, and it shows me this: http://imgur.com/XQIqdG2

So I attempt to launch the app from Eclipse (made by following the directions from this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html ), and it said "No compatible targets were found."

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-not-recognized-by-eclipse

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that earlier

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to successfully run my app on my phone even though my computer says "sd card" and "d2lte" (model of my phone). In Eclipse, you may want to try 'debugging' your app instead of running it, I don't know if it will make a difference but when I click debug I can choose my phone as the device if I have it plugged in. I am  running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 7000 laptop. You said you were running a virtual machine if I understood correctly; you should consider installing linux as a dual-boot option. Then you can choose Windows or Linux when you power on your machine. I imagine it would be easier and would give you more features than just running a VM in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, debugging worked. (At least it made the VM work, but combined with one of the comments from JoaoBiriba's link I was able to get it running on my device.)