# LG G3 Not working with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7-x64

I'm running Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 with ADT plugin and SDK tools.  I've installed the google driver, have set up the USB connection as internet (ethernet), and enabled USB debugging on my device.  I've already looked through and tried all of the answers on this thread [LG G3 device not recognized by Eclipse on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-not-recognized-by-eclipse) to no avail.  Anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: Does your computer even detect your phone?

Comment: Yes, and it's auto installing drivers even though I have auto install turned off.  If I uninstall the driver, unplug, replug, and attempt to reinstall the driver it says it's already up to date.

Comment: Can you see anything from adb devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ADB Driver Installer :

```
http://adbdriver.com/downloads/
```

This free software even can detect if you have corrupted driver. I have used this software since "the beginning of time" and it works accross a wide variety of devices. (Samsung, Lenovo, HTC)

I never tested it on LG, but i believe in this software power. Its just 9 MB, give it a try !

Comment: Thank you!!  This is the only thing that worked for me.  I did have to install the 61833 USB drivers after using the adbdriver installer and switch to MTP and then back to Internet, but I was finally able to launch an app on my device.

Comment: @user2521945 Great! This software seems support all vendors :) Please accept my answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this works for LG. I had been forced to tether my LG G3 to get ADB to recognize it for a while, and I just accepted this as the way it had to be. But this tool detected incorrectly installed drivers and installed good ones, and now ADB recognizes my LG phone immediately, no tethering needed.