# Not able to connect my device with Eclipse for running Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing android application with eclipse.
I have installed google usb driver from sdk manager.
Now i am trying to connect my Samsung GT-I9300, I can see my device on computer list but eclipse dont open dialog to select device, it is still running application on Emulator virtual device.
I am using Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1

Please check screen shots below :

[image]

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Thanks..

### EDIT

[image]

Now i can see device but i can not select it. Its target is also unknown.

[image]

Comment: Did you enable debug on device?

Comment: Check USB Debugging is on in your device or not.

Comment: May i know where did you check.

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24801935/1785412

Comment: @MrNice , I checked in my mobile setting->developer option=> USB debugging. I set it to enabled option

Comment: @SiddharthVyas , Yes i have completed all those steps but still Eclipse open Emulator instead of showing me option to select attached device or Virtual device.

Comment: @Anjum : You need to got to Run configurations option in eclipse and select "Always prompt to pick device" option.

Comment: @Anjum : Right click project --> Run As --> Run configurations --> Target Tab --> Always prompt to pick device

Comment: ok, but still i can not see my device :(, please see edit section in my question for screen shot.

Comment: How should i connect USB PC Connection, via MTP (Mdia Device) or PTP (Camera) ??

Comment: @SiddharthVyas , I can see device now on Android Device Chooser but its target is unknown and i can not select the device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66973/discussion-between-siddharth-vyas-and-anjum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Make the device MTP Connection(Connected as Camera), then reinstall the device driver usuing the following way:

- Choose the device from [device manager].
- update driver ----> browse my computer for driver software ----> let me pick from a list... ----> Have Disk.
- Browse and choose the proper driver, the press OK.
- Restart adb.

Comment: What do you mean by restart adb ??

Comment: Also connected via Camera is PTP

Comment: go to the directory of the `..\sdk\platform-tools` and press **shift+right_click** then choose **open command window here**, then in the command window opened write `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

download [AdbDriverInstaller](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and install device driver when you connect your device

Answer (score 0):

install kies to detect samsung device
http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/