# Android device doesn't appear in eclipse - LG G3

Tags: android, eclipse

I used with Galaxy s3 and it works fine. I switched my phone to LG G3 and I want to run an android application now in eclipse, but when I do run my device doesn't appear in the list of devices.
I did turn on the USB Debugging, I update the last version in the "Device Manager" - it writes to me that my device have the last version (When I do it : [LG G3 device not recognized by Eclipse on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-device-not-recognized-by-eclipse) but it doesn't helps)
Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether LG devices have a special USB driver? Edit: LG does have proprietary USB drivers. Install them.

Comment: Did you try to install a universal ADB driver on your system? Are you running Windows or a unix based system?

Comment: I running Windows 8 system 64 bit. I downloaded ADB drivers but I dont know what to do with it. there is no exe file to install or something. Edit : thats the adb drivers I have been downloaded : http://www.mediafire.com/download/41lx6p71xxit1ax/ADB+Drivers_Updated.zip

Comment: go to the control panel and see if your mobile is correctly detected, do you have the recent drivers from lg in your pc?

Comment: If it is an `inf` file, you can select that one when manually adding a new driver in the Control Panel.

Comment: I can see my device in the "Portable Devices". I never used any LG so I think I have no any drivers in my computer. And DerGolem, In the ADB drivers I have inf file but when I select the file it says me again that my device is up to data - the lastet version. Please try to help me please.

Comment: If your driver is correctly installed, when your device is connected, in the Device Management (which is accessible from the Control Panel), you should see a device called `ADB Interface`. By expanding that one, you should see a device called `Android Adapter ADB Interface`. Some devices require to be explicitly set as `MTP device`. Moreover, you might be required to `authorize your PC, the first time` your device connects successfully as a debug device.

Comment: Ok I'm success to find my device, but now I running my application and in the running it stops, before it load. And it works on the galaxy device. any ideas ? Thanks.