# I can't see my device in Android adb list

Tags: android, windows, adb

I have `LG G3` with `android 5.0 lollipop` and I want to connect it to my laptop with `windows 8.1` OS (For using unity remote).

When I connect my phone I can access to storage but `I can't see my device in adb.exe`. I tried many solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-device-not-recognized-by-eclipse) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb) but nothing work for me.

For now in developer mode I checked  these:

- Stay awake
- USB debugging
- Allow mock locations

And I installed the driver from lg website.

**Update 2:**
Actually I really confused because I think it recognize my device and show `g3` name but I don't know why it can't show my device name in attached device!!!

[image]

**Update:**
Without lg driver installed, my device in device manager is like image below and when I try to update the driver using `Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` it say: `Windows could not find driver software for your device`

[image: My Device without lg driver installed]

And when I install lg driver, my device is like image below and again i can't update driver and it say: `Windows has determine the driver software for your device is up to date`

[image: My device with LG driver installed]

Comment: Maybe you have multiple applications on your windows that uses the adb, if not, try to reset the adb.

Comment: @Yaniv I do that, Please see update 2. tnx

Comment: [Install the drivers](http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-manuals)

Comment: your http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl7Hp.jpg shows you already inside of `adb shell`.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem about usb driver for windows.
instal pda net  will solve your problem

[pda net](http://pdanet.co/)