# Can't connect LG G3 to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, lg

My LG G3 is not appearing in the device list for android studio. I'm on ASUS n550jk with Windows 10.

Things I have done:

- USB Debugging Mode
- Media sync(MTP)
- Camera (PTP)
- Google USB Drivers from Android SDK Manager
- LG USB Drivers
- Switching USB ports
- Restarting PC

Nothing has worked. I got it to work a few months ago on Windows 8.1, but I can't remember what I did.

Comment: Try going through these steps. 
It helped me when i had issues
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-device-not-recognized-by-eclipse

Comment: It only worked for me when setting it to MIDI Device under USB connection settings

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you enable developer options on your phone and check 'Enable USB Debugging'

On your Phone... Go to your settings: Go to "about phone" Tap on "Build Number" 7 times. This enables developer options Go to Developer options (in the settings app) Check - Enable USB Debugging
Did you make sure to install the [adb](http://www.lg.com/us/support) drivers for your phone? Also make sure you have enabled debug mode on your device. If neither of those are the issue, maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-device-not-recognized-by-eclipse) for further troubleshooting help.

When you connect your phone to your computer with Android studio running, you should see a dialog box asking for permission for your computer to debug your phone. Tap Yes and accept those permissions.

You should be set from there! Hit 'Run' in Android Studio and you should be good to go.

Hit me up on here if you have any further questions!

Comment: The support page for the [adb](http://www.lg.com/us/support) drivers in your first link led me to the right drivers. There are many other supposedly correct drivers I can download from other places but this one solved the problem.

Answer (score 26):

As on Android 6.0 device & Windows 10 this worked for me. **Steps 1 & 2 before attaching phone to computer.**

1) Activate developers settings (Settings -> General -> About phone -> Software info -> Press 7 times "Build number" button). After that it says "Now you are an developer".

2) Go back to General settings and press "Developer options". After that find option "USB debugging" and tick that box.
[USB debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXCi.jpg)

3) Attach phone to the computer via USB. Phone will ask "Allow this computer to access your phone data" "Allow". After that you should have "Tap for more USB options" -notification. Choose "Send images (PTP)"

Create "Hello World" -project as an test and try to to select deployment target again.

Comment: Thank you, you save my life. :)

Comment: Using PTP and not MTP made the difference between the phone saying it was in debug mode and the phone actually being in debug mode for me!

Comment: Also Reboot your phone, Restart Adb (or Android Studio), Accept PC connection notification on phone. Device should now be visible in 'Select Deployment target Window'.

Answer (score 4):

Switch USB PC connection from MTP to PTP

Answer (score 3):

LG G3 requires you to 1) Activate developer's mode 2) Enable USB debugging BEFORE connecting your phone to the laptop 3) Accept the computer's RSA fingerprint when installing an apk from AndroidStudio and most importantly 4) Installing the phone on your computer.

Use [this link](http://www.lg.com/in/support/pc-suite) and select your model. Without installing this software you will still be able to charge your phone and access its memory from your laptop but for it to appear as a device in Android Studio, install this.

Comment: This is correct for me. For the G3, I actually had to download the correct drivers on the LG site before ADB could recognize it in Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the need to enable USB debugging BEFORE connecting the phone. Somehow, after an hour of trial, that did the trick for LG G2 Mini d620-r.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem shortly after upgrading to MarshMallow. I had developer options on, but the "USB Debugging" option was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with connection LG G4 phone with Android Studio, and try lots of combination like enabling developer mode, USB debugging, switching USB PC Connection from MTP to PTP and vise versa, restarting phone...But no csucces until I downloaded and installed Windows USB driver from this location http://www.lg.com/in/support/software-firmware and choose LG G4 Stylus. My phone is LG G4 Leather dual sim, but works with selection above.

Answer (score 0):

you should go to `settings->Common->Software info` and click `Build number` 7 times in LG G3

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with my `LG G7`, [this page](https://www.syncios.com/android/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-on-lg-g7.html) helped me solve it.

Essentially, what was missing, besides enabling `USB Debugging`, was enabling `USB Tethering`. For that:

1. Look for "tethering" in your settings search bar.
2. Enable it after clicking on the first option.
3. Now your `LG G7` should appear as `LM G710 (mobile)` under your devices `Android Studio` dropdown menu. Select it as your current main device.
4. *Run* your `main.dart` with the *play* button (or `flutter run` on the terminal). It will also appear as an available device in `VS Code` if you prefer it as your IDE.